# How to reach a Global Scope IPv6 host?

Tags: ipv6

I have setup `DNS64+NAT64` on a machine with 2 interfaces:

`eth0:` public `IPv4` address (connected to outside world)

`eth1:` global scope `IPv6` address: `2001::/64`

I can successfully use `ping6 google.com` on this machine.

Now I want to connect my MacBook to this machine by making it an `IPv6`-only client and perform some tests, but I do not have an `IPv6` address assigned on this MacBook.  I'm wondering, how should I manually assign one so as to route all my `IPv6` traffic (I will disable IPv4 on my MacBook) to this machine, which will be picked up by `DNS64+NAT64` to be converted to `IPv4` requests and sent to the outside world?

---

**UPDATE:**

`NAT64+DNS64` machine is running `Debian`. I installed `Miredo` on my Macbook, and now I have `2001:: IPv6` address; however I cannot ping my Debian machine using it. (Both the notebooks are on wired LAN in the university network and I can ping the `IPv4` address of the machine offcourse)

---

**UPDATE:**

so I installed radvd on the debian machine; and now my macbook gets an IPv6 address from the debian machine and all the IPv6 traffic is routing through the debian machine to make my setup work!

I am also blogging about my setup at http://ipv6transeval.tumblr.com/ if anyone is interested

Comment: What OS is the base machine?  looks like it's linux, but you didn't state?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Then BillThor's answer is correct :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you have been assigned a /64, install radvd and configure it to broadcast on eth1.  Your mac should automatically configure a globally scoped IPv6 address.

Comment: What about translation part? He won't be able to access IPv4 that way.

Comment: @AndreKo: I would expect the NAT64+DNS64 on his server to handle that.  I believe that will be what he is testing.